# Trying to get an image url from AJAX, getting status = 0

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, http, xmlhttprequest

I have an input, say "xxx".
the server returns an image in GET method in: https://website.com/xxx

All I want is for the image that returns when going to that url to be displayed.
Wrote a little script for it but i always get status = 0. I wonder why it is and how can it be 200.

```
<!-- templates/homeDEV.html -->
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

            <form method="GET">
                <p>AJAX Address: <input id="address" type="text" name="address"                             maxlength="64" size="64"></p>
                <p><input type="submit" value="Generate AJAX" onclick="loadImage()"/></p>
            </form>

            <script>
                function showImage(src) {
                    var img = document.createElement("img");
                    img.src = src;
                    document.body.appendChild(img);
                }

                function loadImage() {
                    var theReturn = document.getElementById('address').value;
                    var url = "https://monkey-g.herokuapp.com/monkey/" + theReturn;

                    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

                        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                            showImage(url);
                        }
                    };

                    xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
                    xhttp.send();

                }
            </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `<input id="address" ...` needs to be closed with ` /> </p>`

Comment: @Ghostrydr — Nonsense. This isn't XHTML.

Comment: so does the ajax return an image or a URL for an image? you're contradicting yourself.. which is it?

Comment: @Quentin - You're partially right...Look again.. it needs at least a `>`

Comment: @Ghostrydr - you look again.. there's a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: @Quentin... SONOVA!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running your JavaScript when you click the submit button in a form.

This:

1. Initiates the Ajax request
2. Submits the form
3. Leaves the page
4. Cancels the Ajax request (because there is no longer any JS to handle the response)
5. Loads the new page

Remove the form, and make the button a JS (`type="button"`) button.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to AJAX an image. There's not possible way to stuff an Image from an AJAX request into an image tag. The image tag itself is all you need.

Also, as Quentin said, your page is going to refresh before your ajax call is made anyway if you use a form.

```js
function loadImage() {
  var theReturn = document.getElementById('address').value;
  var url = "http://monkey-g.herokuapp.com/monkey/" + theReturn;
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = url;
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

```html
  <p>AJAX Address: <input id="address" type="text" name="address" maxlength="64" size="64">
  <p><input type="button" value="Generate AJAX" onclick="loadImage()" /></p>
```